# Moodle plugin exception

Tags: exception, plugins, moodle, uninstallation

I was trying to install a plugin called "Socialwall format" on my Moodle site running on a remote server. Before completing installation, it threw two exceptions that is,

It has been detected that your site is not secured using HTTPS. It is strongly recommended to migrate your site to HTTPS for increased security and improved integration with other systems.

PHP setting max_input_vars is recommended to be at least 5000.

How can I fix this?. I am using ubuntu version 22.04.1. I have attached the screenshot as well.

[image: 1]

I expecting this will be a due to some missing in config.php file. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

They are warnings rather than exceptions, so you can continue to use the Moodle site

`max_input_vars` is an easy fix, edit the php file for Apache

```
/etc/php/xx/apache2/php.ini
```

Search for `max_input_vars` and replace the value

```
;max_input_vars = 1000

max_input_vars = 5000
```

Then restart Apache

https://docs.moodle.org/401/en/Environment_-_max_input_vars

Using https is recommended for security but is a bit more complex to set up. It also depends how your server is setup.

There are instructions here - Test it on a local/staging server first. And think about scheduling downtime and putting the site into maintenance mode while the changes are being made.

https://docs.moodle.org/311/en/Transitioning_to_HTTPS